# LuaLaTeX: problem with high symbols in math mode

Tags: math-mode, luatex

A year ago I wrote my thesis and I compiled it using `LuaLaTeX` (I need very much memory because I have a lot of `pgfplots` graphs) and it works pretty good. Today I recompile it and some formulas mess up.

The problem is using symbols with a variable height like square roots and brackets. Below there is a MWE showing the problem and then the images of the result compiling with `LuaLaTeX` or `pdfLaTeX`.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} 
\hbar\omega_{\pm} = \frac{\hbar q}{2} \sqrt{ \frac{\hbar^2q^2}{m^2} + 2c_1^2 + 2c_2^2 \pm2\sqrt{ {c_1}^4 + {c_2}^4 + 2{c_1}^2{c_2}^2\left(\frac{2{g_{12}}^2}{g_{11}g_{22}}-1\right) } }
\end{equation}

\begin{equation} 
\hbar\omega_{\pm} = \frac{\hbar q}{2} \left[ \frac{\hbar^2q^2}{m^2} + 2c_1^2 + 2c_2^2 \pm2\sqrt{ {c_1}^4 + {c_2}^4 + 2{c_1}^2{c_2}^2\left(\frac{2{g_{12}}^2}{g_{11}g_{22}}-1\right) } \right]^{1/2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

**LuaLaTeX**

[image]

**pdfLaTeX**

[image]

The second equation has the same problem with both compilators: the brackets are not high enough compared with the square root. Checking more carefully I see that this problem was present also a year ago. The second problem is instead new and involves only `LuaLaTeX`: I can't nest two square root without obtaining that strange black area....

But the problem disappears if I have no fractions:

[image]

It seems like there is a maximum height of the symbols that can't be overcame

Comment: What version of LuaTeX do you have? You find the information in the first line of the log file

Comment: @egreg `Version beta-0.70.2-2012062323 (TeX Live 2012/Debian) (format=lualatex 2013.6.19)`

Comment: I'm afraid there's a bug with the square root, in that version; with 0.76 I get a good result in the first equation, while the delimiters are too low in the second.

Comment: @egreg Do you think the height of the delimiters is a bug too? Because it is wrong also with `pdflatex`

Comment: Just to inform: everything is OK here using `This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.70.1-2011061416 (rev 4277)  (format=lualatex 2012.3.4)`

Comment: The bracket's height is what it has to be, according to the rules in Appendix G of the TeXbook.

Comment: @egreg how can I update my `LuaLaTeX` version?

Comment: @Red You should install the “vanilla” TeX Live: http://tug.org/texlive

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug now fixed in the current distributions